# How to calculate an angle with a specific additional offset from 45 degrees?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, angle

While making an interactive recreation of a [schematic rail map](https://www.spoorpro.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/spoorkaart-20181.jpg), I discovered that the angle of the diagonal lines are not exactly 45 degrees but have a 1.4 degrees additional offset.

I'm writing a small piece of drawing software in which all lines should snap to certain angles. Snapping to exactly 45 degrees is easy enough:

$$snapped = (\approx bearing \div 45) \cdot 45$$

However, my problem lies in writing a function that performs a mapping as follows:

- $45 \Rightarrow 46.4$
- $-45 \Rightarrow -46.4$
- $135 \Rightarrow 133.6$
- $-135 \Rightarrow -133.6$

Is there a 'clean' calculation for the above mapping without explicitly defining the inputs and outputs?

Comment: What would be the input of the function? The angle? Or the x$ and $y$ coordinates on the map?

Comment: @Andrei The angle is the input. It would be perfectly fine to have a function which maps diagonal input angles (45, 135, ...) to output angles (46.4, 133.6, ...). Using the modulo operator it's easy enough to determine which angles are diagonal. 0, 90, 180, … should be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because your $x$ and $y$ units on the map have slightly different lengths. If they would have the same length, $$\tan\alpha=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta  x}$$
In your case, $y$ is longer by about $5\%$. So $$\tan\alpha'=\frac{1.05\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$
For computer programs is nice if you use $\mathrm{arctan2}$ function. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). So the answer would be $$\alpha'=\mathrm{arctan2}(1.05\sin\alpha,\cos\alpha)$$
Depending on the implementation, you might need to transform input to radians and output to degrees. So in Python, I would have a function like

```
import numpy as np 
def ang(inp):
    si=np.sin(np.radians(inp))
    ci=np.cos(np.radians(inp))
    return np.degrees(np.arctan2(1.05*si,ci))
```

Answer (score 1):

The line $y = x$ is modified to have more slope by a factor of $ \tan{46.4^\circ} $

and the line $y = -x$ is modified to have more negative slope by the same factor.

Therefore, $ \phi = \text{Atan2} \left( \cos \theta,  \tan(46.4^\circ) \sin \theta \right) $

where $\phi$ is the output angle and $\theta $ is in the input angle.